# Interpretation of an Exercise in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, intuition, problem-solving, uniform-distribution

The exercise is as follows:

> Starting at 5:00 A.M., every half hour there is a flight from San Francisco airport to Los Angeles International airport. Suppose that none of these planes is completely sold out and that they always have room for passengers. A person who wants to fly to L.A. arrives at the airport at a random time between 8:45 A.M. and 9:45 A.M. Find the probability that she waits (a) at most 10 minutes; (b) at least 15 minutes.

The first sentence of the solution says:

> Now the passenger waits at most 10 minutes if she arrives between 8:50 and 9:00 or 9:20
>   and 9:30; that is,
>
> if $5 < X < 15$ or $35 < X < 45$

I agree with this procedure IF we only consider the cases where no matter what, the passenger won't wait more than 10 minutes. But the passenger could very well not wait for longer than 10 minutes if he arrives at ANY time, so I feel like we are excluding a lot of cases here. Where am I going wrong? Or, much more unlikely, where is the author going wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated because probability has been, is, and will forever be a nemesis of mine!

**EDIT**

It seems as though I understood the first sentence as saying that every $30$ minutes starting at 5:00 A.M., there is exactly one flight that takes off WITHIN the $30$ minutes time interval. It seems I am supposed to understand it as flights take off at exactly the beginning of the hour and exactly in middle of the hour. I don't think either interpretation is incorrect given the language.

Comment: So I am not clear, you are just talking about the case (a) right ?, and case (a) is indeed atmost 10 minutes, so you do want to exclude other cases, what is the problem ?

Comment: yes just case $a)$. The problem is the author is only considering two cases where she waits at most $10$ minutes when she can wait at most $10$ minutes in a bazillion more cases @SagarM

Comment: I dont think there are a bazillion more ways, between 8:45 and 9:45 there are two flights at 9:00 and 9:30, which leaves with only 2 ways to wait atmost 10 minutes as described by the author

Comment: @SagarM What would you say to the following scenario: She arrives at 9:08, and only waits 7 minutes because this flight takes off at 9:18.

Comment: "Starting at 5:00 A.M., every half hour there is a flight from San Francisco airport to Los Angeles International airport": The flight is not taking off at random times, it takes of at 5:00, 5:30, 6:00, 6:30, 7:00,7:30,8:00,8:30, 9:00, 9:30,10:00,10:30, 11:00

Comment: I see, may you read my edit? @SagarM I don't see how the first sentence forces one to understand it that way. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Umm...Technically I would agree with you, but I don't think any author would choose to be so ambiguous, my rule in such cases would always be to choose the "simpler" explanation, and in this case it is that the flight takes of at an interval of half an hour starting from 5:00

Comment: That is a great rule of thumb. Thank you for your input :) @SagarM

Comment: Let it be that the passenger arrives at $X $ minutes past 8:45. Then the event mentioned under a) can be described by means of $X $ and that's what is  done by the author. It remains now to find the probability of event $\{5 <X <15\}\cup\{35 <X <45\} $.

Comment: @drhab '...Well done, good and faithful servant!...' (Matt. 25:21)

Comment: Yep "Starting at 5:00 A.M., every half hour" is unambiguous to mean on the half hour, every half hour. It would have to be "Starting at 5:00 A.M., within every half hour there is a flight" or similar to mean not on the half hour to my ears.